# Dynamically Displaying both First Name and Last Name as Select Options

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, html-select

I am trying to dynamically display both the first name and last name of people from a database. I have been successful in displaying the first name, but I am not sure of how to do this with the last name. Any help would be appreciated :)

PHP:

```
$swimmername_query = "SELECT * From Swimmers ORDER BY FirstName ASC";
$swimmername_results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $swimmername_query);
echo "<option value=>";
echo "Select Customer";
echo "</option>";

while ($displayname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($swimmername_results)){
echo "<option value = '".$displayname['FirstName']."'>".$displayname['FirstName']."</option>";
            }
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: For it to Be "First Name Last Name". At the moment it only prints "FirstName"

Answer (score 2):

You can just concat it directly in your query like so:

```
$swimmername_query = "SELECT *, CONCAT(FirstName, '-', LastName) AS FullName From Swimmers ORDER BY FirstName ASC";
$swimmername_results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $swimmername_query);
echo "<option value=>";
echo "Select Customer";
echo "</option>";

while ($displayname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($swimmername_results)){
     echo "<option value = '".$displayname['FullName']."'>".$displayname['FullName']."</option>";
}
```

Or concat the strings inside the while loop:

```
$swimmername_query = "SELECT * From Swimmers ORDER BY FirstName ASC";
$swimmername_results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $swimmername_query);
echo "<option value=>";
echo "Select Customer";
echo "</option>";

while ($displayname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($swimmername_results)){
    $fullname = $displayname['FirstName']."-".$displayname['LastName'];
    echo "<option value = '".$fullname."'>".$fullname."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have ID column as a value and merge firstname with lastname together in your query.

```
$swimmername_query = "SELECT SwimmersID, Firstname || ' ' || Lastname SwimmerName From Swimmers ORDER BY FirstName ASC";
$swimmername_results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $swimmername_query);
echo "<option value=>";
echo "Select Customer";
echo "</option>";

while ($displayname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($swimmername_results)){
echo "<option value = '".$displayname['SwimmersID']."'>".$displayname['SwimmerName']."</option>";
```